# Problems overriding paintEvent with PySide

Tags: python, overriding, pyside, paintevent

I've subclassed the QPlainTextEdit class and have tried to override the paintEvent function so that I can draw a line number area onto it.

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    super(CodeEditor, self).paintEvent(e)
    qp = QtGui.QPainter()
    qp.begin(self)
    self.drawLineNoArea(qp)
    qp.end()
```

When the program runs I get this output:

```
QPainter::begin: Widget painting can only begin as a result of a paintEvent
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

My best guess is that the function hasn't been overridden properly, but I'm really not sure. Can anybody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the viewport to the QPainter, same as with lists and trees.

```
def paintEvent(self, e):
    super(CodeEditor, self).paintEvent(e)
    qp = QtGui.QPainter()
    qp.begin(self.viewport())
    self.drawLineNoArea(qp)
    qp.end()
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I ended up using a bit of a hack to work around it due to time constraints, but good to know for future projects!